# Question about `std::packaged_task<R(Args...)>::get_future`

Tags: c++, c++11, future

As per the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/get_future), which says that[emphasise mine]:

> std::future get_future();    (since C++11)
>
> Returns a future which shares the same shared state as ****this***.
>
> get_future can be called only once for each packaged_task.

1.What's the `*this` at here? The instance of `std::packaged_task<R(Args...)>`?
Could somebody shed some light on this matter?

2.**Must** I call `get_future()` (in the current thread) **before** the packaged_task is invoked(by another thread)? Should I pay attention to any possible race condition?

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) page, I understood that the `*this` refers to the `task` instance of `std::packaged_task<int()>`. Therefore, your assumption was true.

```
// future from a packaged_task
std::packaged_task<int()> task([]{ return 7; });    // wrap the function
std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();            // get a future
std::thread t(std::move(task));                     // launch on a thread
```

Comment: *From this page, I understood that the `*this` refers to the task instance of std::packaged_task<int()>. * Sorry, I can't see any relation between `ths page` and `I understood that the *this refers to the task instance of std::packaged_task<int()>.`.Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: The `get_future()` is a member function of `std::packaged_task<int()>`, hence you can make a call like `task.get_future();`. In a member function, `this` pointer points to the calling object. That's why `*this` refers to the `task` object.

Comment: I see, what about the second question? Any possible race?

Comment: In all examples, the `get_future()` is called before starting the operations. I'm not sure if it is mandatory, but I would follow the examples and call it before things get complicated.